# React child component don't update after parent state changed

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-state

This question has been asked several times but I can find answers only for class component and not functional components, and my issue seems a bit weird to me so I am interested in why React behaves like this.

I want to create a timer in React Native.

When the timer ends, it triggers the `onTimeEnd` method, that updates the state of the App component and triggers the `useEffect` on the `timeInSec` prop of the Timer component.

When the reset button of the App component is pressed, it updates the state of the App component but does not trigger the `useEffect` the Timer component. I can't understand why.

I hope you will see what I mean with my code (I removed other functionalities that I believe do not affect this code).

**`App` component:**

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput } from 'react-native'

import Layout from './components/Layout'
import Timer from './components/Timer'

const App = () => {
    const defaultTime = 20

    const [timeLeft, setTimeLeft] = useState(defaultTime)

    const onTimeEnd = () => {
        setTimeLeft(defaultTime)
    }

    const resetTimer = () => {
        setTimeLeft(defaultTime)
    }

    return (
        <Timer
            timeInSec={timeLeft}
            onTimeEnd={onTimeEnd}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={resetTimer}>
            <Text>Reset</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
}

export default App
```

**`Timer` component:**

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { View, Text} from 'react-native'

const Timer = (props) => {
    const [timeInSec, setTimeInSec] = useState(props.timeInSec)

    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            const newTime = timeInSec - 1
            setTimeInSec(newTime)

            if (newTime === 0) {
                clearInterval(interval)
                props.onTimeEnd()
            }
        }, 1000)

        return () => clearInterval(interval)
    })

    useEffect(() => {
        // This useEffect is triggered when the state of the App component changes from the onTimeEnd function,
        // but not when it changes from the resetTimer function. Why ?
        setTimeInSec(props.timeInSec)
    }, [props.timeInSec])

    return (
        <View>
            <Text>{ timeInSec }</Text>
        </View>
    )
}

export default Timer
```

Comment: See [derived state - React](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/conquering-derived-state-57087036b230#:~:text=While%20most%20React%20components%20are,to%20some%20degree%20by%20props.)

Comment: Thanks @ShivamJha ! Actually I found out the problem had nothing to do with the useEffect... The component just didn't rerendered after the state updade because I was updating it with the same value. So obviously the useEffect wasn't triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem had nothing to do with the useEffect... The component just didn't rerendered after the state updade because I was updating it with the same value. So obviously the useEffect wasn't triggered.

Comment: @ShivamJha I created a new `Number` from the `defaultTime` constant : `setTimeLeft(new Number(defaultTime))`